# If there is no other enemy within 5 feet of the initial target of the Green-Flame Blade cantrip, must the fire leap to a friendly creature in range?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, cantrips

When I use the *green-flame blade* cantrip to attack a creature, then it can bounce the flame to a creature within 5 feet of my target.

If there is no enemy within 5 feet of my target, but there is a friendly character within that distance, must the friendly character take the fire damage? Or can I simply ignore the bouncing in this situation, meaning the friendly character is not damaged?

Comment: Extremely related: "[Does the secondary damage of the Green-Flame Blade cantrip damage the caster if no other targets are available?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83157)"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### It is optional.

The description of the [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) spell states (SCAG p. 143, emphasis mine):

> you **can** cause green fire to leap from the target to a different creature of your choice

It says you “can”, indicating there is a choice.

Notably, this wording was introduced in the [November 2020 errata for the *Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide*](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf). Prior to this change, the description of *green-flame blade* said:

> On a hit, the target suffers the attack’s normal effects, and green fire leaps from the target to a different creature of your choice

Comment: This came up in our game a few months ago, and our DM ruled the same way.

Comment: What's interesting is that in the [linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83157/27388) has a different wording. In November of 2020 an [errata](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2020/11/10/errata-sword-coast-adventurers-guide-green-flame-blade-and-booming-blade-fix/) was released with the "can" wording.